# Check if external picture exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have pictures from other website like Facebook, Twitter or Instagram and I would like to check if they exists before I display them. I've tried :

```
  def remote_file_exists?(url)
    url = URI.parse(url)
    Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
      return http.head(url.request_uri)['Content-Type'].start_with? 'image'
    end
  end
```

But it tells me that I don't have access to the server, something like "no connexion could have been done" (I can't translate in english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to query facebook, twitter or any such service without proper authorization.  If you find a work around, that would be unethical :)

If at all you want to do it, you'll need to register your app with the services you want to access and get the right API credentials.  However, folks still need to sign up with your app for you to access their private data.

Comment: Thanks ! It doesn't make sense to me because I can still display these picture if they exist, so I was hoping that there was a way to check that they exist on my side

Comment: where are you checking those pics from?  your browser? try signing off from your fb, twitter, instagram accounts and checking the pics again.

Comment: I simply use `<img src="..."/>` but I would have thought that I could check if they exists before displaying them